# Are demonyms colloquial? If so, should we use them in writing?

Tags: demonyms

Here's a Wiki [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities) of demonyms for cities in the world. Scrolling down the page, you'll see the header of the table is **Demonyms (colloquial)**. Does this mean all demonyms for cities are colloquial? If not, why did they write it like that?

Comment: Just about everything depends on context. So the question is moot.

Comment: I wondered if they meant that any colloquial names were in brackets, but no. The entry for Liverpool says "Liverpudlian, Scouser" and I would think that the latter is the colloquial one.

Comment: If you want to know why they wrote it like that, go to the Wikipedia page, click on "Talk" above the article title, then on the top right click "Add topic", and post your question on Wikipedia which the people who edit the page on Wikipedia are likely to see and answer. I'd guess it's because the list contains formal demonyms followed by colloquial demonyms, but they'll give you a more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's the other way round: most "official" demonyms are also what you'd call someone colloquially. At the very least you won't sound weird using the non-colloquial version.
But sometimes there is a nickname for inhabitants that you wouldn't use in polite society. Often over time this common name will get more accepted and used in official texts, at first ironically but later as a simple statement of fact.

Answer (score 2):

When this list was created back in 2006, there were three columns. One for the Adjective, one for the formal demonym, and one for the colloquial demonym.  By 2010 someone had edited to combine the last two columns, but put the colloquial demonym in brackets "Liverpudlian (Scouser)"

Then between 2010 and now there was apparently some debate about whether certain demonyms were actually formal or colloquial and if the formality was citable or "original research", so the table was edited to remove all the brackets.  But (for some reason) the column heading wasn't edited.

Generally demonyms like "Londoner" or "Liverpudlian" that are produced regularly from the city name are not colloquial, but those such as "Scouser" or "Monkey Hanger" are colloquial. And you should always take care not to stereotype.  That is you should not assume a particular personality based only on the place that someone lives.

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the page now, the heading on the column is simply "Demonym". Apparently someone has edited it to remove the reference to "colloquial". @JamesK gives a history of the page, and from that it sounds like this column heading was simply a mistake: someone changed the contents of the column but forgot to change the heading.

Personally, I am deeply hurt and offended that my home town, Lapu-Lapu, is not included on the list. :-) I am frankly not sure what the accepted term is for someone from here. A Lapu-Lapuan? A Lapu-Lapuano? I always just say, "someone from Lapu-Lapu".

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked for your city? In case you have found it, can you use the demonyms listed there in writing?

For answering those questions and yours, I've looked for my city, Málaga, in Spain. This is what I found: Malagenean, Malagueño, Malacitano.

I don't know how much Malagenean is used because it is the English translation of the Spanish word malagueño. You can find both Malagueño or Malacitano in writing, there is no much difference between them apart that the second one, Malacitano, is close to the Latin roots of Spanish and can be considered a bit more erudite.

Somehow I think that you're mixing two concepts colloquial and slang. For example Madrid, capital of Spain, inhabitants call themselves "gatos" (cats). Such demonym is not listed and it may be considered slang but it's also colloquial and you can find it in writing. All depends on the main audience that you write for and what you want to transmit.

To summarize: There is no problem on using any of the demonyms listed. That "colloquial" there is totally superfluous because no other kind of demonyms are listed. Why did they use it? I don't know how to contact the one that edited the entry in Wikipedia to add that.

Comment: I did notice there are a few cities where they added more (New Yorkers are apparently "knickerbockers", never heard that one) but yeah, they should remove the ones where it's the same, for clarity.

Comment: Those demonyms in English for Malaga are quite obscure. Maybe in some literary text...

Comment: @Lambie What's the non-obscure demonym then?

Comment: There isn't one.